# Ruby-build fails because 'The Ruby openssl extension was not compiled'

Tags: ruby, openssl, rbenv

Whenever I try running rbenv install [version], after a few minutes the ruby-build fails and I get the following output:

```
Installing ruby-3.1.2...
ruby-build: using readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (macOS 12.2.1 using ruby-build 20220426)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/rf/fpyjcz390_s3_s72h94q2n100000gp/T/ruby-build.20220719092817.73171.RatvHz
Results logged to /var/folders/rf/fpyjcz390_s3_s72h94q2n100000gp/T/ruby-build.20220719092817.73171.log

Last 10 log lines:
The Ruby openssl extension was not compiled.
ERROR: Ruby install aborted due to missing extensions
Configure options used:
  --prefix=/Users/random.person/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2
  --enable-shared
  --with-readline-dir=/usr/local/opt/readline
  --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl@3
  CC=clang
  LDFLAGS=-L/Users/random.person/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib
  CPPFLAGS=-I/Users/random.person/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include
```

I had fixed this temporarily in the past but it keeps happening.  How do I set up the openssl correctly so I can get rid of this?

Comment: while I was posting this I let this : `brew --prefix openssl@1.1
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)" RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)" rbenv install 3.1.2` run in the background and it just worked wtf. still, I want to know if there is a way to solve this properly

Comment: I might be a bit late here, but do you have the `openssl@3` homebrew formula installed? If not, give that a try. Also, any chance you have the `RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS` environment variable set? Cause I think ruby-build will by default download and build its own version of OpenSSL for Ruby.

Comment: I had a similar problem, but only when installing JRuby versions (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77183865/7492260)).